# Error creating tree from pre-order and in-order

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

I read somewhere that given a (preorder and inorder) or (Postorder and inorder) can uniquely define the tree.
I tried my own example and found that I am getting the wrong results.
The details are given below

Pre-order:-7,6,4,1,3,5,2,8
In-order:- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
[Basically, it is a binary search tree(just by looking at in-order )]
I made the tree using this information and found out that the post-order corresponding to this is-2,3,1,5,4,6,8,7
Now I look to my tree and find preorder. It was not matching with the given order it is like- 7,6,4,1,3,2,5,8

Why is this error?

Comment: You asked a very good question. Please, look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because **7,6,4,1,3,5,2,8** is not a valid pre-order for a BST.

If we follow the procedure, we get this tree from above given pre-order and in-order

```
        7
       / \
      6   8
     /
    4
   / \
  1   5
   \
    3
   /
  2
```

And now, if we find the pre-order by traversing the above tree we get 7,6,4,1,3,2,5,8. This pre-order is correct for a BST. And we also get this pre-order from using post-order and in-order of the above tree.

Why pre-order **7,6,4,1,3,5,2,8** was wrong?

If we look carefully, we are breaking at points 7, 6, 4, 1, 3.
But after 3 it should be **2** not 5, because we are in recursion of root node, left node and right node of a pre-order. We cannot go to breaking at point 5 without breaking at 2 before.

As, 2 and 5 have no child nodes, it gave us a tree, found the post order and now we are in confusion why are we not able to produce the same pre-order again?
It is simple because **7,6,4,1,3,5,2,8** was never the pre-order.

Let me make it more clear if we had numbers 1.5 and 5.5 in the BST. We are in the pre-order recursion and have broken at point 3 to get {2,2.5} on left and {} on right, but how can we move to breaking at 5, without breaking at 2. We are in recursion, remember this.

Moreover, **constructing the tree using a pre-order and a sorted in-order, and if we are not able to generate the same pre-order is a method of checking if the given pre-order was a valid pre-order or not.**

Check this article : [valid pre-order of a BST](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-array-can-represent-preorder-traversal-of-binary-search-tree/)

Use the given program in link and run it on your pc to check your pre-order is valid or not for a BST.